# Fancybox is behaving abnormally?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using fancybox in my website which is working good. What I am actually doing is I am opening one fancybox and when it opens, i have a link to open a second fancybox. When I click on that link, it opens the second fancybox, which is fine.

The problem with the second fancybox is that when I minimize the web browser and try to scroll to the window in order to see the last line of fancybox. Now comes the pain the fancybox automatically jumps to center, there is no benefit of scrolling the window.

If I minimize the web browser for the first fancybox then there is no such problem, but with the second fancybox there is. Why is this problem arising?

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<style>
</style>
<!-- <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        loop        : false,
        maWidth     : 500,
        maxHeight   : 500,
        minWidth    : 500,
        minHeight   : 500,
        autoPlay     :false,
        fitToView   : true,
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',



              afterLoad: function() {
              this.title += '<div style="background-color:;width:100%;float:left;"><div style="background-color:;width:40%;float:left;>fdfdg</div><div style="background-color:;width:40%;float:left; onclick="secondfb();"><button>link to another fancybox</button></div></div>'; 

             this.title +='</br>';
              },

              helpers : {

              title: {
              type: 'inside'
              },
              }
              });
              });
function secondfb()
{
$("#vik").fancybox({
        loop        : false,
        maWidth     : 500,
        maxHeight   : 500,
        minWidth    : 500,
        minHeight   : 500,
        autoPlay     :false,
        fitToView   : true,
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',



              afterLoad: function() {
             this.inner.prepend( '<div id="emaildiv"><form id="emailform" method="POST"  onsubmit="checkemailform(this);return false;"><div><img src="/images/RentCan.png" height="92px" width="160px" alt="bccondos.net" border="0" style="max-width: 160px;height: auto;"/></br></div><fieldset style=""><div style="width:30%;min-height:100px;float:left;"> First Name <input type="text"name="fname" id="fname" readonly value=""style="width:250px;"></input></span> Last Name <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" readonly value="" style="width:250px;"></input>  Email <input type="text" style="width:250px;"id="email" readonly value="" name="email"></input>Phone Number<span style="color:red;">*</span><input type="text" style="width:250px;"id="phoneno" name="phoneno"></input></div><div style="width:40%;min-height:100px;float:right;margin-right:5%; ">Comment<textarea  style="min-height:150px;width:250px;" id="rentcanformfeedback" name="rentcanformfeedback"></textarea></div></fieldset><div style="width:100%;float:left;;"><fieldset><span class="fl_n"><center><img id="captcha" src="/securimage/securimage/securimage_show.php"   alt="CAPTCHA Image" /></center><hr>Enter the code above here:<input type="text" name="captcha_code" id="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6" /><span id="captchamsg" style="display:none;color:red;">Above  Code not matched Please Try Again!</span> Cannot read the image click <a href="#" onclick="captcha_changeimg()"><b> HERE </b></a>to refresh</span> </fieldset><fieldset><input type="checkbox" name="choices" id="ii" value="ii" >I am interested in this listing and other similar listings<span style="color:red;">*</span><br><p style="margin-left:20px;">Please describe yourself (Choose one)<span style="color:red;">*</span></p><input type="radio" name="choices" id="hmfr" value="hmfr">Help me find a rental.<br><input type="radio" name="choices" id="iwai" value="iwai">I want additional information.<br><input type="radio" name="choices" id="ijc" value="ijc" >I am just curious.<br><input type="radio" name="choices" id="iwpr" value="iwpr">I want to post a rental.<br><br><input type="checkbox" name="cbox12" value="confirmation" id="cbox12">  I confirm that the information I have provided is true and correct and acknowledge that management will suspend my account if my information is found to be false. Click here for our <a href="/Privacy_Policy_Rentcan.html" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>. <span style="color:red;">*</span></fieldset></br><input type="submit" value="Send" ></input><br><br></div></form></div>');
             this.title +='</br>';
              },
             helpers : {
             title: {
              type: 'inside'
              },
              }
              }).trigger('click');


}

</script>

</head>
<html>
<a rel="group" class="fancybox" caption="This is 1st caption" href="images/img1.jpg" ><img src="images/img1_thumb.jpg" alt="image1"/></a>
<a rel="group" caption="This is 1st caption2"class="fancybox" href="images/img2.jpg"><img src="images/img2_thumb.jpg" alt="image2"/></a>

<div id="vik"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us some basic code so that we can help you

Comment: please see my code below

Comment: It looks like there is a lot of unnecessary code included. It would be beneficial for anyone who is reading this to only see the code that is relevant to the question.